# How to match these two outputs and checked matching subject/vakke

Tags: laravel

I want to match these two outputs and if they match they should be checked...

```
public function edit($id)
    {

        $classes = Grade::with('subjects')->get();
       
        $vakkes = Vakke::where('user_id', $id)->get();

        return view('profiles.edit', compact('classes', 'vakkes')); 
           
    }
```

edit.blade.php

```
@foreach($class->subjects as $key => $subject)
                                @foreach($vakkes as $key => $vakke)
                                    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox mt-2">
                                        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input @error('subjects') is-invalid @enderror" id="{{$class->id}}{{$subject->id}}" 
                                        name="vakkes[{{$class->id}}][]" value="{{ $subject->id }}" 
                                        {{ ($user->grades->pluck('id')->contains($class->id) && $vakke->pluck('name')[$key]->contains($subject->name)) ? 'checked': ''}}/>
                                        <label class="custom-control-label" for="{{$class->id}}{{$subject->id}}">{{$subject->name}}</label>
                                    </div>   
                                @endforeach
                            @endforeach
```

Im definitely doing something wrong here...

This is what the dump and die of `dd($classes)` and of the `dd($vakkes)`

[image]

[image]

Comment: are you getting an error? looks like you are trying to call a method on a string

Comment: @lagbox Yes I am getting this error: Call to a member function contains() on array (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\Kwakhanya-Centre\resources\views\profiles\edit.blade.php)

Comment: are you calling `toArray()` on the collections when dumping them?

Comment: @lagbox Yes I do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `$vakke` is a model instance you can just get the `name` field and if its an array you can use `in_array` to do the check against the subject name:

```
in_array($subject->name, (array) $vakke->name)
```